# UK visit visa application concerns and ties to home country: complex situation

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, student-visas

I returned to pursue a bachelor's degree through distance learning from the UK. It took me 5 years because of the pandemic and political instability. Now, I graduated and I plan to travel to the UK for a summer (July) graduation ceremony in 2024. However, I'm worried about a potential visa refusal due to being unemployed and aged 30.

In my country, many people, including myself, don't maintain substantial savings in banks due to the political situation. I do have cash on hand, but it's limited. My father will sponsor me for the trip and accompany me to the graduation. We recently sold a house and converted the proceeds into gold. Currently, neither of us has active bank transactions. We own an apartment and recently bought a condominium (with the first instalment paid).

I've also received an offer to study for a Master's degree at a UK university, which I've accepted by depositing the tuition fees. In such case, I must return to my home country to apply for a student visa (I can't change to student visa while on a visit visa inside the UK).

I inquired with a travel agent about my situation, and their response highlighted concerns because of my age, unemployment, and lack of bank deposits. Even though my father will sponsor me, it seems the chances of obtaining a UK visitor visa are slim.

1. Would the acceptance letter from the UK university not be considered as evidence of my ties to my home country? I have to return home regardless to apply for the student visa.
2. If I start depositing money in the bank, it will take three months to establish proof of sufficient funds, which might appear suspicious.
3. I also possess gold. Should I provide buy and sell receipts for the gold, demonstrating the amount I intend to deposit in the bank?
4. Do I also need to provide affidavit of return?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: @badjohn. I'm from Burma

Answer (score 1):

The acceptance letter from the UK university is a good evidence of your intention to return to your home country, but it is not enough by itself. You also need to show that you have strong ties to your home country. The fact that you own an apartment and a condominium is helpful, but you need to provide proof of ownership and value. You also need to show that you have enough money to cover your travel expenses and living costs in the UK, and that the money is from a legitimate source.

A better option might be to ask your father to transfer the money from his bank account to yours, and provide his bank statements and a letter of sponsorship. This way, you can show that your father is supporting you financially and that he has enough funds to do so.

You need to provide buy and sell receipts for the gold, as well as bank statements showing the deposits and the balance. However, this might raise some questions from the visa officer, as they might wonder why you suddenly sold the gold and where you got it from. They might also suspect that the money is borrowed or not yours.

Comment: We usually do advice not to transfer money from the sponsor into the account of the person traveling, as that is seen as a loan which might have to be repaid before the travel.

Comment: There are countries where it's generally not a good idea to keep money in bank accounts, so people don't. When I was in Argentina no one bothered posting real estate prices in Pesos since no one would ever pay or accept  Pesos for a transaction like this. What are people from those countries to do?  One would think that the UK would have an alternative process for this type of visitors.

Comment: @Hilmar UK/USA is kinda strict on their sponsorship.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, David. I am from Burma. As @Hilmar mentioned, not everyone keeps money in a bank account, and even if they do, the amount might not be significant. This becomes an issue when applying for a visa. What if I start depositing money now?